# How to use v.patch or v.clean and v.clip?

Tags: qgis, grass

I want to know that I am using GRASS GIS correctly. I'm having trouble merging these two shapefiles

- http://www.gisdeveloper.co.kr/download/admin_shp/EMD_201902.zip
- http://www.gisdeveloper.co.kr/download/admin_shp/LI_201902.zip

How would you go about the process of dealing with shapefiles which have errors like this?

I've tried importing and cleaning using both QGIS and GRASS but I always end up with warnings like this:

```
WARNING: Number of centroids exceeds number of areas: 32665 > 20038
WARNING: Number of incorrect boundaries: 62688
WARNING: Number of centroids outside area: 12461
WARNING: Number of duplicate centroids: 3210
```

I've tried changing the snapping threshold for v.in.ogr but it doesn't seem to make a difference

when I try doing v.patch it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdBey.jpg

I'd like to end up with something that looks like this but on one layer with no overlap so that there is a 1 to 1 relationship with every space on the map: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5TWi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use QGIS ([SAGA](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.7/shapes_tools_2.html) tool) to merge the layers and then import the new layer to GRASS environment:

```
Vector ‣ Data Management Tools ‣ Merge vect Layers
```

[image: New Shp QGIS]

[image: New Shp GRASS]

Or you can also create a pipeline using bash in which you automate this function by importing the layer in grass.
I hope it helps you :)